# What are the rules for using : it's or its?

Tags: possessives, personal-pronouns

I am often corrected on *StackExchange* for writing **it's** instead of **its**

Few minutes ago :
`I start a game by it's shortcut` ==> `I start a game by its shortcut`

I am (quite) sure that when I was young, I've only learned **it's** and I never seen **its** anywhere then (But it was 35 years ago...).

What are the rules for using **it's** or **its** ?

Comment: The 'apostrophe s' for the possessive is _not_ used with _it_ so as to distinguish it from _it's_ as an  abbreviation for _it is_. I was taught this at school 50 years ago and it is still true!

Answer (score 2):

You're not alone, half the English-speaking world seems to muck up this trivially simple rule.

"it's" is a contraction of "it is".

"its" is the possessive form of "it".

I'm *sure* this question must have been asked before.

Comment: What is that animal? **It's** a dog. What is it doing? The dog is lying on **its** blanket.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey "It's lying on its blanket", even.

Comment: "It's" can also be a contraction of "it has".

Comment: @rjpond "It's true that it's been lying on its blanket."